# Chess engine threefold repetition detection leads to incorrect play

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, chess

I am trying to implement threefold repetition detection in my chess engine, but the method I use leads to incorrect play. I check for one repetition of the position in the current search space or two repetitions "behind" the root. This approach is used by Stockfish too but it makes my engine weaker (ELO score drops significantly when testing).

Each position in the history of the game has a zobrist hash index.

Threefold repetition detection:

```
 bool Eval::isThreefoldRepetition() const {
        const std::deque<GameState>&history=internal_board.getHistory();
        int repetitions=0;
        uint64_t hash=internal_board.getGameState().zobrist_key;

        for(int k=history.size()-2;k>=0;k-=2){
            if(history[k].zobrist_key==hash){
                if(k>=root)//found repetition in current search space
                    return true;
                //else we need 2 repetitions that happen before the root
                repetitions++;
                if(repetitions==2)
                    return  true;
            }
        }
        return  false;
    }
```

Search:

```
 int Eval::negamax(int depth, int alpha, int beta, Color color) {

        if(isThreefoldRepetition())
            return threefold_repetition;

        uint64_t hash=internal_board.getGameState().zobrist_key;
        int alphaOrig=alpha;
        Transposition node=TranspositionTable::getInstance().getTransposition(hash);
        if(node.getType()!=NodeType::Null &&node.getDepth()>=depth){
            if(node.getType()==NodeType::Exact)
                return node.getValue();
            else if(node.getType()==NodeType::LowerBound)
                alpha=std::max(alpha,node.getValue());
            else if(node.getType()==NodeType::UpperBound)
                beta=std::min(beta,node.getValue());
            if(alpha>=beta)
                return node.getValue();
        }

        if (depth == 0) {
            return getHeuristicScore(color);
        }
        std::vector<Move> moves = movegen.getAllMoves();
        if (moves.size() == 0) {
            if (movegen.isInCheck(color))
                return checkmate - depth;//try to delay the checkmate
            return stalemate;
        }
        int best = -infinity;
        Move best_move;
        setRating(moves);
        std::sort(moves.begin(), moves.end(), compare);
        for (const Move &move:moves) {
            if(!hasTimeLeft()){
                premature_stop=true;
                break;
            }
            internal_board.makeMove(move);
            int down = -negamax(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, getOpposite(color));
            internal_board.undoLastMove();
            if(down>best){
                best=down;
                best_move=move;
            }
            alpha = std::max(alpha, best);
            if (alpha >= beta)
                break;
        }

        if(!premature_stop) {
            //save the position in the transposition table
            NodeType node_type;
            if (best <= alphaOrig)//did not affect the score
                node_type = NodeType::UpperBound;
            else if (best >= beta)
                node_type = NodeType::LowerBound;
            else node_type = NodeType::Exact;
            TranspositionTable::getInstance().addEntry(Transposition(node_type, hash, depth, best, best_move));
        }
        return best;
    }
```

Notice that I can't check for a 'real' threefold repetition because a position will not be repeated thrice in the search space when using transposition tables.

Is my method of evaluation wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at research on the [GHI problem](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Akihiro_Kishimoto/publication/244456577_Correct_and_Efficient_Search_Algorithms_in_the_Presence_of_Repetitions/links/5406ed810cf23d9765a8243f/Correct-and-Efficient-Search-Algorithms-in-the-Presence-of-Repetitions.pdf)?

Comment: I am out of my depth here, but if `hash` means what I am used to here, it seems to me that you have to do a full comparison if the hashes match to see if the two positions were really identical.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError In many game implementations they don't do full comparisons and tolerate any errors that may result. It helps that Zobrist hashing works very well.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error  those are zobrist hashes, each chess position hashes to its own unique hash (the collisions are very rare) , so one may assume that if two zobrist hashes are identical, the board configurations and the castling rights are the same.